# Pine Script code to show label with 'low' of the bar

Tags: pine-script

I wanted to see a label above the bar with "low" value of the bar if close < open, I searched a lot but "tostring" command is giving an error. Any help is appreciated.

I'm a code-dummy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should not give you any errors.

Here is an example which works:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

var label _l = na

if (close < open)
    _l := label.new(bar_index, low, str.tostring(low), yloc=yloc.abovebar)
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome @vitruvius Do you offer freelancer support for custom requests?

Comment: Yes, I do. You can find me and other trusted pine developers supported by Tradingview from [here](https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000601677-where-can-i-find-a-reliable-pine-programmer-to-hire/).